# Hint algorithm problems in a Bejeweled clone

Tags: c#, xna

I've got a slight issue with my hint algorithm for my Bejeweled clone. Right now, the following code produces a 'hint' at the top left of the board every time I hit the H key (the key for showing a hint).

```
public bool AreThereMoves(Gem[,] gem2)
{
    hintGems.Clear();
    return (AreThereMovesDown(gem2) && AreThereMovesRight(gem2));
}
public bool AreThereMovesRight(Gem[,] gem2)
{
    hintGems.Clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < gem2.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gem2.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            Gem[,] gems3 = new Gem[gem2.GetLength(0), gem2.GetLength(1)];
            Array.Copy(gem2, gems3, gem2.Length);
            SwapGemsCheck(x, y, x + 1, y, ref gems3);
            if (CheckMatches(gems3, 2) || AreThereSpecialGems(gems3))
            {
                hintGems.Add(gems3[x, y]);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public bool AreThereMovesDown(Gem[,] gem2)
{
    hintGems.Clear();
    for (int y = 0; y < gem2.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gem2.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            Gem[,] gems3 = new Gem[gem2.GetLength(0), gem2.GetLength(1)];
            Array.Copy(gem2, gems3, gem2.Length);
            SwapGemsCheck(x, y, x, y + 1, ref gems3);
            if (CheckMatches(gems3, 2) || AreThereSpecialGems(gems3))
            {
                hintGems.Add(gems3[x, y]);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Right now, the code is a bit kinky for the special gems hints. As in, it won't show a hint on a hypercube.

When I tried using the plain `AreThereMoves()` method in the check for end of game, it didn't function at all. I currently have it testing both Down and Right methods in the end of game check.

My question is: How would I go about changing this so that it puts the hint over an actual move?

If there is any other information needed, please don't hesitate to say so.

EDIT:

Here's the hint popup code:

```
public void ShowRandomHint()
{
    if (hintGems.Count == 0) return;
    Gem g = hintGems[Main.rand.Next(hintGems.Count)];
    g.Sparkle(Main.rand);
    AddText(new Vector2((GetGemPosition(g)[1] - 1) * gemSize + (gemSize), (GetGemPosition(g)[0] - 1) * gemSize + (gemSize)) * new Vector2(1.08f, 1.08f), "HINT!", 2f, Color.Aqua, outlineColor: new Color?[1] { Color.Gold }, amt: .01f);
}
```

And the code that calls it(in Board.Update):

```
if (CheckMoving()) hintTimer++;
else hintTimer = 0;
if (hintTimer >= hintDelay)
{
    ShowRandomHint();
    hintTimer = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to paint the screen differently and only showing three `bool` returning methods?

Comment: @Preston I'm not sure I understand your question. I should probably go back and edit my question to be more explanatory. Hang on, I'll do that.

Comment: I think you want `(AreThereMovesDown(gem2) || AreThereMovesRight(gem2));`. You don't want to know if there are moves down AND right, but if there is A move. Correct?

Comment: @TyCobb It's actually an `if (!AreThereMovesDown(gems) && !AreThereMovesRight(gems))` check in the end of game. I consolidated the end-of-game-check with the hint algorithm. As in, I'm not using the regular `AreThereMoves()` method. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @BrianHansen http://sscce.org/ Keep this in mind - as it stands it's incredibly difficult to tell what you're actually asking, and the code you've provided calls out to a half dozen classes and methods no one is going to be familiar with. Regarding your other response, `!f(x) && !g(x)` doesn't have the same truth table as `f(x) || g(x)`, if you are trying to determine if there are moves either down or right, TyCobb's logic is correct and neither of yours are.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I'm silly XD. It works, it just doesn't work when I load up the board. I have to level up for it to work properly. I think it has to do with how I save and load the board, so that's a completely different problem.